# What affects LRFD strength reduction factors?

Tags: structural-engineering

In LRFD strength reduction factors depend on the material and the applied load (shear, axial moment) too? Or just material? Are they also called resistance factor?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain all information that is pertinent. Don't assume that any other user will know what you are talking about. Be specific so that there is no confusion. To your specific question, what reference manual are you using? I am sure that Euro Code has differences from AISC or AASHTO, etc.

Comment: Anyone who can answer this, will know with 100% chance LRFD. Anyone who doesn't know what LRFD is, do not need to or cannot answer this question anyway. In other words, if I provided details such as what is LRFD in the question, the ones who didnt know it, would still not be able to answer, and for the ones who knew, it would be very redundant. This is a general question which does not need any specific code ref. It is a conceptual question that asks how the factors were developed. Providing source is irrelevant. I cannot edit. I cannot ask it other way

Comment: Someone knowledgeable can answer this in a few sentences. I roughly know the answer. But I still wanted to know what someone else may say. I will not edit the question. If it doesn't work and you are moderator, you can delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general speaking, the strength reduction factor reflect the confidence on a structural element's ability to withstand a certain type of loading. It is derived statistically from both the research experiments and the past experiences; and it is based on the structural response/behavior of a certain type of material subjected to a certain type of load. In this sense, you are correct in calling it a "resistance factor", which is always less than 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is all I needed I guess.